# System History Linux 5.11 (NOT BASH)

Tags: logging, system

I run an application that checks system history for a primary machine, the third party application is querying the system history table at the same time its being written to, this causes an error on the third party application. I feel that if I archive some of the history table it will clear the error.

How do I archive system history in Linux 5.11?
Not the bash history.

Comment: Sorry about that corrected the issue

Comment: Also, the history tag is marked as [do not use](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info). You should probably choose a better one. Also, by system history, did you meant log?

Comment: I do mean system history log or table not sure which it is.

Comment: Again, the table tag is marked as [do not use](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/table/info). Please take the time to read the definition of tags before choosing them. Sometime some tags should not be used or might not mean what you think they mean. And it's important to properly tag your post as it will help it being seen by people that might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

There is no prevision to archive system_history  or system_historytmp

You can back up the table system_history, but you cannot backup system_historytmp.

The only option you have would be to run a selectfile or selectout on the system_history, or system_historytmp.